# Creating a Complex Diagram with TikZ in LaTeX, Including Itemized List and Citations

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I'm currently working on a LaTeX document and I need to include a diagram that looks like the one shown in the attached image. After some research, it seems that TikZ might be the tool to achieve this. I've attempted to create the diagram using both Tikzmaker and Tikzit, but I'm encountering difficulties in getting it to work as intended.

Here's a brief description of the diagram:
[image]

I have a couple of specific questions:

Diagram creation:
I need help repeating the row of figures

This is what I got so far

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % Rectangle on the left
  \draw (0, 0) rectangle node[text centered, align=center] {Rectangle 1} (3, 2);
  
  % Arrow between the first and second figure
  \draw[->] (3.5, 1) -- (4.5, 1);
  
  % Rectangle in the middle
  \draw (5, 0) rectangle node[text centered, align=center] {Rectangle 2} (8, 2);
  
  % Arrow between the second and third figure
  \draw[->] (8.5, 1) -- (9.5, 1);
  
  % Circle on the right
  \draw (10, 1) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{TikZ Figure with Shapes and Arrows}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Image of what the code produce:
[image]

Itemized List: I'd like to have an itemized list inside the first square of the diagram. Is it possible to achieve this with TikZ? How can I incorporate an itemized list into a TikZ node?

Citations: Lastly, I need to include citations within the itemized list. How can I format and include citations for each item in the list? Are there any specific packages or commands I should be aware of?

I appreciate any assistance or guidance you can provide. LaTeX and TikZ are relatively new to me, so detailed explanations or code snippets would be incredibly helpful. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. As to your second question, you can just use `\begin{itemize} \item First \item Second \end{itemize}` within a node and it should output correctly. With citations you can just use `biblatex` and then put `\cite{...}` in the node, in a document I am writing now I have a node where I use `\printbibliography` so that my reference list is contained in the same image. Your first question is too broad however, questions should be specific, welcome to TeX.SE though!

Comment: Welcome. // Please make it a habit right from the to post only code, which will compile, i.e starts witn `\documentclass` and ends with `end{document}`. By doing so, you resolve lots of guessing we'd have to make about your preamble. // It may also be a good idea, at least in this case, to add a screenshot of what your code produces. Thank you

Comment: Thank you for commenting! I have updated the post according to your recommendations.

Comment: @Anton, two suggestions: 1) Take repeting tours through the pgfmanual, with focus on the 4 tutorials https://tikz.dev/ . 2) Reconsider your idea: it does not give very readable results. Less is more - more or less ;-)

Comment: Note that [text width=...] is equivlent to to putting the contents inside a \parbox, and [align=...] it eqivalent to putting the contents inside a one column tabular.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I started to code your question. From that point on you should be able to complete it by yourself.

- I placed the rectangles as nodes and used relative positioning, so that they always have the same distance to each other.
- to help with the spacing I used the tikzlibraries `calc` and `positioning`.
- To maintain the same style in a column I defined three styles. So all the rectangles/circles in one column have the same width.
- the package `enumitem` is loaded to remove the indent of the itemized list and the white space above it.
- as mentioned in the comment of @JamesT you can use a bibliography and the command `\cite{...}` in a node text if you want to cite something. This should be explained sufficiently in other posts.
- You could also define some styles for the spacing of the nodes (or include it in the existing styles). In that way you don't have to change the values in every node but only in the style definition, if you want to change the spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\tikzset{style_large/.style={
  inner sep=3pt,
  text width=7cm,
  minimum height = 2.5cm,}
}
\tikzset{style_small/.style={
  inner sep=3pt,
  text width=3cm,
  minimum height = 2.5cm,
  align = center,}
}
\tikzset{style_circle/.style={
  inner sep=3pt,
  text width=2cm,
  circle,
  align = center,}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % Rectangles on the left
  \node[style_large,draw] (Rect1) {\footnotesize\begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt,leftmargin=*]
      \item Reading into the information a common-knowledge-based interpretation
      \item Recalling a personal experience that applied to a similar situation
      \item Evoking beliefs that transfer to the situation
  \end{itemize}};
  \node[style_large,node distance = 0.5cm, below = of Rect1,draw] (Rect2) {\footnotesize\begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt,leftmargin=*]
      \item Transfering features of a product to a new one
      \item Using an affinity with a culture or a service
  \end{itemize}};
  
  % Rectangle in the middle
  \node[style_small,draw,node distance = 1cm, right = of Rect1] (Rect11) {Assumption Driven perception};
  \node[style_small,draw,node distance = 1cm, right = of Rect2] (Rect22) {Metaphor Activation};

  % Arrow between the first and second figure
  \draw[->] (Rect1) -- (Rect11);
  \draw[->] (Rect2) -- (Rect22);
  
  % Circle on the right
  \node[style_circle,draw] (Circ1) at ($(Rect11.south east) + (2cm,-0.25cm)$) {Analogical Reasoning};
  
  % Arrow between the second and third figure
  \draw[->] (Rect11.east) -- (Circ1.west);
  \draw[->] (Rect22.east) -- (Circ1.west);
  
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{TikZ Figure with Shapes and Arrows}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this really helped me understand how to do this myself! Much appreciated

Comment: Glad I could help. If you don't understand a part don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an other approach, which may help you get started and look up relevant keywords and concepts (!) in the [pgfmanual](https://tikz.dev/). It's not as nice, as [DraUX solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/694268/245790), and it has some remaining problems. However, a development path for a drawing looks similar.

How to arrive here?
[image: result]

#### Document class

Almost always it's easier using `\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}`, as you aren't limited by arbitrary page geometries.

Once you're done, change it to the class you use, or copy the `Tikz` related code into your document, or use other methods like `\input`, `\subfiles` etc.

#### [Nodes and their shapes](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes)

This is one of the basic concepts to master, which makes drawing (and keeping aligned) extra shapes around text for example obsolete.

Associated are self-defined styles, like so, which you assign to `\node` and `\draw` statements:

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}[% define your own styles here
    hdr/.style={red,font={\large\bfseries}},%               formatting the header-nodes
    blk/.style={draw,align=center,minimum width=4cm},
    lblk/.style={blk,font=\small},
    ell/.style={draw, circle,align=center},
    >=Stealth,%                     changing all arrow-tips
 ]
...
```

- hdr: for the header line, puts some color, larger and bold font
- blk: draws the nodes shape (default is rectangle) at a minimum width; use `\\` for [multilines](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#sec-17.4.3)
- lblk: "inherits" from blk, but uses small font for the overlongtextionitemlines
- ell: was intended to turn the nodes circle shape into ellipses later, but skipped that for now; more important is the alignment for multiline text

#### [Positioning the nodes](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#sec-17.5)

Using absolute coordinates may be natural to start with. So for a try I started with a 5cm-raster.

More sophisticated placement is done using `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}` or the matrix approach from the tutorials.

#### Text inside \node {}

Though you can put Latex code for tables there, using itemize seems to have problems. Some kind of vertical box seems to be needed.

However, using `\vbox` spoiled the drawing, so I ended up using `\parbox`. As you can see, it has unresolved problems:

- width becomes a parameter inside the {text} itself, rather than in the style-statements
- you need to adjust the list environment for a better look

```
    % ~~~ the various boxes ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    % ~~~ items need some kind of vertical box ~~~~
    \node[lblk] (C3) at (0,-5) {\parbox{4cm}{
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Manifesting text that is far too long
                \item Finding unexpected extremely long text
        \end{itemize}}};
```

#### Connecting

Once you have all nodes in place, connect them via their names you introduced earlier. Using [anchors](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#sec-17.5.1) `.east` and `.west` give you the desired connection points.

```
    % ~~~ connections ~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[->] (C3) -- (E3);
    \draw[->] (E3.east) -- (L2.west);
```

#### Suggestions

Consider developing drawings as a kind of doing pottery with code:

- start somewhere
- make changes
- unify, i.e. make duplicate parts accessible in one place only
- apply continous refinement
- save (versions) often (even more often)

#### Full code

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}


\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[% define your own styles here
    hdr/.style={red,font={\large\bfseries}},%               formatting the header-nodes
    blk/.style={draw,align=center,minimum width=4cm},
    lblk/.style={blk,font=\small},
    ell/.style={draw, circle,align=center},
    >=Stealth,%                     changing all arrow-tips
 ]
    % ~~~ Headline ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node[hdr] (C0) at (0,0) {Codes};
    \node[hdr] (E0) at (5,0) {Emerging themes};
    \node[hdr] (K0) at (10,0) {Creative logics};
    
    % ~~~ the various boxes ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    % ~~~ items need some kind of vertical box ~~~~
    \node[lblk] (C3) at (0,-5) {\parbox{4cm}{
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Manifesting text that is far too long
                \item Finding unexpected extremely long text
        \end{itemize}}};
    
    \node[blk] (E3) at (5,-5) {Serendipitious\\detection};  
    \node[ell] (L2) at (10,-8) {Associative\\thinking};
    
    % ~~~ connections ~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[->] (C3) -- (E3);
    \draw[->] (E3.east) -- (L2.west);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer; I will most certainly dive deeper into the existing documentation of Tikz!

Comment: You will love it after a while. The basic ideas are not too difficult, while it‘s certainly overwhelming in the beginning. Best thing is to try many simple Tikz code yourself.